# Why won't .live() work with my custom event, but .bind() will?

Tags: jquery, triggers, live

I'm thinking it's a bug, but as of 1.4.2, `.live()` is supposed to support custom events. Here's a quick little demo: http://jsbin.com/erofi/edit

Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong with my triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.live()` must be used on a selector. Whether an event target element matches the selector string is checked at event time. This is hinted at in the doc ‘caveats’:

> DOM traversal methods are not fully supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.

`$(document)` isn't a selector. If you look at `$(document).selector`, which is the remembered selector string that `live()` uses for matching, you get an empty string, hence `live()` not working.

Since selectors only match elements, you can't `live`-bind against `document`. Then again, since `document` never changes, there is no need to: a normal binding would be fine.

(This is unfortunate API design. It should have been `$.live('selector', 'event', function() {});` IMO. `$('selector').live()` makes it unclear what it's actually doing. And certainly there should have been an error when you call `live()` on a wrapper without a selector.)

Comment: That is why .delegate() was introduced, works 'better' and makes things a lot more clear

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delegate events to the 'Document'.
Not exactly sure, but I think `.live()` will not bubble up so far.

Try to `.bind()` and `.trigger()` to other elements under `document.body`